# PHP Read txt file line by line

Tags: php, file, line

I have this PHP code:

```
$myfile = fopen("index.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

//rewind($myfile);
fseek($myfile, 0);

while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $line=fgets($myfile);
    echo $line;
    echo strpos($line,":");
    echo "<br />";
}

fclose($myfile);
```

**index.txt** contains the following data:

```
:a
1:b
2:c
```

**result:**

```
:a 3
1:b 1
2:c1
```

I'm having problem with the function `strops`, it doesn't give the accurate position number.

As you can see in the result, I get the number `3` while it should be `0`
and there is a white space added between the letter `a` & the number `3` (and between the letter `b` & the number `1`).  Why is that?

As you can see above, I tried to set the file pointer position to 0, but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're reading a raw text file with a UTF-8 BOM tag or something first (that your echo _is_ printing, you just can't see it). You need to use [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) to make it unicode friendly.

Comment: Trim every line and then check, `$line=trim($line);`

Comment: Are you sure that is all the text file has? Because given this code above, it behaves exactly as expected. The space between the `$line` and position can be explained as there is a newline at the end of each line which in html will be collapsed down to a single space character. But the number 3 doesn't make sense unless there are additional characters. Here is a basic representation of your code minus reading from the file and it works as expected. https://3v4l.org/7id1U

Comment: @h2ooooooo , that gives :a 1

Comment: @JonathanKuhn , yes that is everything the text file has, nothing more,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.txt has UTF-8 encoding. But commonly used is "UTF-8 without BOM". Difference between them is that the 1st one has three bytes at the beginning of the file (ef bb bf). You should change the encoding of your index.txt file.

The other universal solution (no matter has file the BOM or not) is to check for the BOM in your string (just for the 1st line of the file). Below is the function for checking and removing BOM bytes. Just apply it to your $line: **$line=removeBOM(fgets($myfile));**

```
function removeBOM($text) {
    if(substr($text, 0, 3) == pack('CCC', 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)) {
        $text= substr($text, 3);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Using **mb_strpos** function also shows the correct result. But if you're planning to process the data any other way, you may confront with some other unexpected processing results, because the **$line** variable will still content three unneccesery bytes at the beginning. To avoid such problems you should remove this bytes by using **removeBOM** function.

Comment: wow very good solution, I already tested mb_strpos as suggested above but it didn't work while your solution worked for me, now is not it expensive to call the removeBOM function for each line? as I understood it should be called for the first line only, so I' thinking about declaring variable $i=0; , and ask in the while if ($i==0) { $line=removeBOM(fgets($myfile)); $i++; } else { $line=fgets($myfile); } to detect the first line, do you have another way of detecting first line?

Comment: I can see that it adds a white space between letters and numbers for all lines except the last line,

Comment: @eawedat, no, it's not mandatory to check for the first line.

Comment: so how would you do that? because I'm not willing to call the function removeBOM for each line,,

Comment: It just looks like whitespaces in the output. But in fact it's new line symbols. You can remove them from your variable by using **trim**

Comment: , I think it should be called only for the first line because as you mentioned above the difference between UTF-8 , UTF-8 BOM , would be in the first line of the whole text file,

Comment: If you don't want to call removeBOM for each line, use $i variable as you've proposed above. 
You also can do that a bit another way - without performing $i++ operation for each line. Just use boolean variable and change it value once:

    $ifFirstLine=true;
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $line=fgets($myfile);
        if ($ifFirstLine) {
            $line = removeBOM($line);
            $ifFirstLine=false;
        }
        echo $line;
        echo strpos($line,":");
        echo "<br />";
    }